# ActionScript how to compile .as to binary machine readable format

Tags: compilation, actionscript, binary, mxmlc, compc

I am looking for an option for converting my .as ActionScript3 files to binary format before distribution. I tried mxmlc and compc but both are converting source to bytecode which is reversible. Is there any way to hide your source code completely?

thanks in advance

BB23850

Comment: All ActionScript compilers; comic,mxmlc,flacCC,as2,etc... emit ABC into the SWF to be run by Flash's VM...   ActionScript ofuscation is the best you can do...

Answer (score 0):

As Flash Players can only read bytecodes, but not binary machine code, it is obvious you won't be able to do so. But there are other means of obfuscating your code from getting decoded easily.

If your target is to create stand-alone executable files, then consider SWFKit Pro or similar application. SWFKit store swf as encrypted file, only decrypt when required.